# Is okay to bring an empty mason jar in your carry on?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

There is no liquid. I'm giving my friend a going-away present and inside is a mason jar full of prayers of encouragement whenever she needs it. So is that allowed?

Comment: Mason jars are glass, right? Just check if glass is allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but where are you flying? Where will you be going through security?

Comment: Like @Flimzy says, some countries have different rules on what you can bring. Where is she travelling from/to?

Comment: I'm not sure this should be closed, yes there are different restrictions in different countries but nowhere that I know of prevents you bringing glass on-board and a mason jar isn't any more or less dangerous than a bottle of something from duty free. Only thing I'd think is that security (wherever) may want to open it.

Comment: She is going to Colorado